# Is there such a thing as an unsafe LIKE pattern?

Tags: sql, security, sql-like

Say I have a website open to the public and some JS generates an `SQL LIKE` pattern which is passed to the server.

The server uses this expression without validating it in a SELECT command:

```
 SELECT ... WHERE (User has rights to this record) AND (field) LIKE @LikePattern
```

`SQL injection` won't be an issue because the pattern is passed in as a parameter. Using '%' as a pattern isn't a problem either as the left hand side of the AND restricts the records found. ('%' might even be one of the patterns generated by the JS.)

Invalid patterns might cause an error, but so long as my code is ready to handle the exception thrown from the SQL client library, the invalid pattern shouldn't cause an adverse situation. (Shouldn't it?)

Is there such a thing as a malicious or unsafe `LIKE` pattern? (Maybe a pattern that could cause a loop or need an unreasonable amount of processing or cause an unplanned lock?)

Comment: Is this for any SQL database system or a specific one? There may be system specific extensions to `LIKE`.

Comment: Please always include the DBMS you are using (Postgres, Oracle, ...). I'd consider `'%'` to be an "unsafe" pattern because it essentially means: "get me all rows from that table". Now if that table contains 100 million rows is your application able to handle that? If not, this could be used for a DoS attack

Comment: I don't know which DBMS I'm going to go with yet, so I'm sticking with standard SQL as much as possible for now.

Comment: I think this might be better suited to [security.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there aren't any `LIKE` patterns that are any more "unsafe" than a simple `"%"`, which would of course match all valid rows.

This, of course, is assuming that you have adequate protection for the sort of SQL injection faults you could have with any plain-text field.